# Scons can't be run from Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, scons

I have Scons and Cygwin installed on Windows XP SP2. When i call Scons from Cygwin i get the following error message:

```
bash: scons: command not found
```

what could be the problem, and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using direct path to file 'scons'? if it solves the problem, you should add this path to cygwin's PATH variable (`export PATH=$PATH:newPath`). you can see it by executing: `echo $PATH`

Comment: Yes that solves the problem if i do like "/cygdrive/c/Python26/Scipts/scons.bat". Without the extension ".bat" it does not work. Anyway, how do i make the path permanent, will it work if i add to the windows path?

Comment: check if you have ~/.bash_profile. if you do, simply add at the end of the file `export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Python26/Scipts/scons.bat`. if you don't have it, create it and add the `export` command, as above.

you can also read sth about linux environmental variables.

Comment: Thanks it worked, now i can type scons.bat at the cygwin window.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use scons.bat as in

```
scons.bat --clean
```